# VB.NET write just in the first line of file

Tags: vb.net

I used over four different methods to get the text from a online text file: www.mysite.com/filedata.txt and overwrite it to another file.

Everything works, but I have only one problem. Everything is written in the first line and not the original format.

Example:

From:

```
Hello
Hi
Hi
```

To:

```
HelloHiHi
```

Here is just an example of a correct code which I'm using, but it doesn't work:

```
Using client As New WebClient()
    client.DownloadFile("http://www.mystie.com/filedata.txt", 
        Application.StartupPath & "\file.txt")
End Using
```

Comment: I strongly suspect it *is* in the original format, but that that format uses `\n` as a line break. Try opening the file in an editor like Sublime Text which can handle both Unix and Windows line breaks.

Comment: Thanks! I will try.

Comment: Can you post downloaded file?

Comment: is the downloaded  file created using windows machine... ? and how it was created ?

Comment: No need for download file since I'm creating a new file in a different software for each attempt.

I just created a pastebin with the content from my text file: http://pastebin.com/raw/bz1F3y7w I'm really sad, why is this happening. I even tried what Jon said and didn't work.

Comment: Sufyan Jabr yes. Was created by right click, create new text document. Just as everyone else do.

Comment: I think that this file is not using `\r\n`  ... instead its using `\n` ... try replacing  `\n` with `\r\n`

Comment: I tried everything. It just doesn't want to work...

Comment: It seems like Visual Studio's Textbox and Notepad cannot read these lines, but advanced text editors such as Notepad or Sublime Text read them. What is happening here?

Since I'm creating that text file using Notepad. Maybe while I'm using Filezilla to transfer the text file it convert into something else or something. I really don't know and I'm so sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is using a different [line-break style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) that is not recognized by the edit control.

There are three different types of line-break styles that are in common usage: the Windows style (CR LF), the Unix style (LF), and the classic Mac style (CR).

Windows controls like the TextBox control naturally require the Windows style, CR LF. The corresponding escape characters for C# would be `\r\n`; on VB, you use `ControlChars.CrLf` or `vbCrLf`. On Unix, LF (`\n`, or `ControlChars.Lf`/`vbLf`) is more commonly encountered. If you are getting a file from an external source, like the Internet, it probably uses Unix-style line breaks, which aren't recognized as line breaks by the Windows TextBox control. The reason it works in what you call "advanced text editors" is that they support *all* these different styles of line-break characters.

This is exceedingly trivial to fix. Perform a character replacement on the string, replacing LF with CR+LF, before you display it in the TextBox.

```
' Download the file
Dim path As String = Application.StartupPath & "\file.txt"
Using client As New WebClient()
    client.DownloadFile("http://www.mystie.com/filedata.txt", path))
End Using

' Read the file's text in as a string
Dim filedata As String = File.ReadAllText(path)

' Fix up the line endings
filedata = filedata.Replace(ControlChars.Lf, ControlChars.CrLf)

' Display the text in your TextBox
myTextBox.Text = filedata
```

Comment: Such amazing and well done explication, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve everything by switching from textbox to richtextbox.